# Capture cancelling event for Google Sign-in web

Tags: google-signin

I am implementing google Sign in for my web application as describe in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in. Instead of embedded "Google Sign-In button", I made a custom button which trigger a click event to this function "GoogleAuth.signIn()" as stated in Reference. Everything working fine, if user click the button and proceed with the sigin flow. However, the problem was after the button is clicked and the singin window is shown. User now decided to cancel the singin, but no api function call can be use to capture this event and response accordingly to this user action.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthsignin

You can check whether Promise returned by GoogleAuth.signIn() has been resolved (which means successful sign-in) or rejected (one option is user clicked cancel).

```
function onFailure(error) {
  alert(error);
}

function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  alert(googleUser);
}

auth2.signIn().then(onSignIn, onFailure);
```

Comment: Hi, I originally thought the same. However, cancellation of signin process doesn't reject the promise, and the promise remains unsolved. As stated in the reference too, "A Promise that is fulfilled when the user successfully authenticates and grants the requested scopes.". Am i miss something here. Thanks

Comment: onFailure doesn't seem to trigger, at least on api2's instance.